# Environment variables in PowerShell with a dot (.) in the name

Tags: powershell, environment-variables

I know I can access environment variables in PowerShell using `$Env`. For example, I can access `FOO` with `$Env:FOO`.

I can't figure out how to access the environment variable called `FOO.BAR`.

`$Env:FOO.BAR` doesn't work. How can I access this from within PowerShell?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

To access any kind of PowerShell variable where the name contains non-alphanumeric characters, use the ${…} notation as in:

```
${env:variable.with.dots} = "Hi there"
${env:variable.with.dots}
```

This works for variables in any drive (registry, filesystem, etc.)

Comment: This also works for the dash character, e.g. `${env:My-Environment-Variable}`

Answer (score 8):

Use the .NET method to get the variable:

```
[Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("FOO.BAR")
```

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
Get-WMIObject Win32_Environment -filter "name='foo.bar'"
```