# Is it allowed to have windows environment variable name to have dot?

Tags: windows, powershell, variables, environment

I tried to set environment variable as `aaa.bbb` in `powershell` from windows platform however it looks like it does not like `.`.

This works.

```
$Env:aaa = "testvalue"
```

This fails.

```
$Env:aaa.bbb = "testvalue2"
```

Is it possible to have environment variable name to have `.`?

Comment: While there is a funky syntax override for `$env` (per Booga Roo's answer) I personally prefer `[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable` for any non-trivial work. More keystrokes, but also a lot more explicit, which I consider a good thing when you're modifying the environment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Environment variables in PowerShell with a dot (.) in the name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312314/environment-variables-in-powershell-with-a-dot-in-the-name) or [How to set environment variable with dot in name using powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51784643/150605)

Comment: One thing to keep in mind with using `[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable` is that the changes persist across sessions, where-as using `$env:` does not.  Which to use will depend on the desired behaviour.

Answer (score 5):

You can set the desired variable by enclosing it in brackets like this:

```
${Env:aaa.bbb} = "testvalue2"
```

Note that you'll need to reference the variable by including the brackets but tab completion helps(at least on PowerShell 5.1).

Slightly less cluttered in appearance is the `New-Item`/`Set-Item` as mentioned by eryksun:

```
New-Item -Path Env:aaa.bbb -Value "testvalue2"
```

I see the option `[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable` Jeroen Mostert provided has done the trick for you, per the comments.

Comment: Thank you for your time to provide a feedback. For some reason that didn't work out. I was told ```the input to an assignment operator must be an object that is able to accept assignments```. Jeroen Mosert's suggestion worked.

Comment: We can also use `set-item -path env:aaa.bbb -value testvalue2`.