# How to store an environment variable in a .NET Core console application?

Tags: .net-core, environment-variables

Following the [example found here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/storage-blobs-dotnet-quickstart), the code requires [setting an environment variable](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/storage-blobs-dotnet-quickstart#put-the-connection-string-in-an-environment-variable) in the command line before running.

`setx storageconnectionstring "<yourconnectionstring>"`

Is it possible to store this variable somewhere inside of a .NET Core console application? How would it be accessed by the code if this is possible?

Comment: you can just use a variable static, injected, constant... the purpose of environment variables is for one or both of several scenarios: the value is secret and you don't want it compiled into the code, the value changes per environment, probably more

Answer (score 3):

You can set the environment via command prompt (cmd), powershell using this syntax:

```
setx variable_name "value_to_store_as_a_string"
```

or by using the **System Properties** (right click *This PC*, select *Properties*, then click *Advanced system settings*) window and clicking the *Environment Variables...* button (you can see all user & system environments and create, edit or delete them).
These will be persisted between restarts.

Or back to your question, you can use a config file such as *app.config* (which is an XML file) or *appsettings.json* (which is a JSON file). There are several ways to access it.
Here is a sample *appsettings.json* file:

```json
{
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "System": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information"
    }
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "SQL": "Data Source=servername;Initial Catalog=databasename;User Id=myuser;Password=complexpassword;",
    "MongoDb": "mongodb://username:password@10.0.0.2:27017,10.0.0.3:27017,10.0.0.3:27017,10.0.00.4:27017/?replicaSet=myreplicaset"
  },
  "variable_name": "string_value",
  "boolean_variable_name": false,
  "integer_variable_name": 30
}
```

1. 

```cs
var appSettings = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings;

string myVariable = appSettings["variable_name"];
```

2. 

```cs
public static IConfigurationRoot Configuration;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var configBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");

    Configuration = configBuilder.Build();
    
    string myVariable = hostContext.Configuration.GetValue<string>("variable_name");
}
```

3. 

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
    {
        config.SetBasePath(basePath: Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
        config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true);
        config.AddEnvironmentVariables();
    })
    .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
    {
        string myVariable = hostContext.Configuration.GetValue<string>("variable_name");
    })
    .RunConsoleAsync().Wait();
}
```

You can read another post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46940811/12163640).

You can read more at MS documentation from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.configurationmanager?view=netcore-3.0).

Comment: How do you translate the .json schema into ENV variables?  For example : setx   ConnectionStrings.SQL = "value"

Comment: Here is [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56430794/12163640) about your question.

Comment: If my previous comment is not what you were looking for, please clarify or maybe ask another question separately.